# How to configure Apache 2 to allow access to files on local drives of computer?

Tags: angularjs, apache, angularjs-directive

I'm doing a project where I'm using directives characteristic of AngularJS. Code of my directive looks like this:

```
app.directive('programListing', function() {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope: {
            listing:'='
        },
        templateUrl:'js/directives/programListing.html' 
    };
});
```

Whenever I try to load `index.html` on Chrome it gives: `Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.` error. I tried loading `index.html` through Apache server 2 but it gives: `Not allowed to load local resource` error, due to the fact that my `index.html` file contains some images from local drives. So, how to configure Apache 2 so that it access files from local drives of my computer, so that I can do my work offline too. Thanks in advance!! :-)

Comment: Does it load if you remove the images? What does your image's `src` attribute look like? I hope it's note `file:///` (;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer!! The problem get solved by slightly changing the image address on the local file. Firstly, I placed the image file inside `htdocs` folder of Apache files, then I used this as my address to the file: `http://localhost/image-name.jpg` This solved the problem.